# C# using powershell to use tails

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to using c# to excute powershell command get content and use wait:

```
Get-Content -path 'C:\\Users\\shahel.ahmed\\Desktop\\test123.txt.txt' -wait -tail
```

When ever I excute the above in c#, the query puts me on hold. I want to see the data every time the file get updated.

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    int num = 1;
    PSDataCollection<PSObject> data = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {

        Console.WriteLine("\nEvaluating 'Get-Command Write-Output' in PS Core Runspace\n");
        string output = String.Format("Get-Content -path 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test123.txt' -wait -tail {0}", num);
        var results = ps.AddScript(output).Invoke();
        Console.WriteLine(results[0].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(results[1].ToString());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So the target is to get the last line of a `txt` file, when something changes?